# Include bad groups in the matches

Tags: c#, regex

I have a string like this:

> &l&mmabc&od&l&r&mef&lg&l&e&j&rh

I want to get the following matches and groups. (Consider the parentheses to be groups and lines to be matches)

```
(&l&m)(mabc)
(&o)(d)
(&l&r&m)(ef)
(&l)(g)
(&l)(&e&j)
(&r)(h)
```

So far, I have got this:

```
(&[lmnor])+(\w+)
```

The results of the match are as follows:
[image]
You can see that the substring `&l&e&j` are not included in the matches. I know it's the problem with `\w+` but I can't seem to figure out how to include those matches.  The first group should only contain anything which matches `&[lmnor]` (It can contain multiple of those if they are close together. That is the reason I used `+`)The second group should contain anything other than those letters.
`(&[lmnor])+(.*)` doesn't work. `(&[lmnor])+^(&[lmnor])+` doesn't either.

Comment: Just put ej into the class. i.e. `(&[lmnorej])+(\w+)`

Comment: @PetSerAl, that works :D. Would you mind explaining what `(?!&[lmnor]).` does?
@sln, that doesn't work. If I do that, the last match (i.e `&rh`) is affected (No longer exists) Also, it can be any character(s) other than `&[lmnor]` there in place of `&e&j`

Comment: @EmpereurAiman: `(?:(?!&[lmnor]).)+` is a tempered greedy token. It matches any text that is not starting `&[lmnor]` substring. However, I think you do not want to include spaces, right?

Comment: @stribizhev, thanks . I'll look it up. I'm pretty new to regex (Just started learning today). It's ok for spaces to be there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> You can see that the substring `&l&e&j` are not included in the matches. I know it's the problem with `\w+` but I can't seem to figure out how to include those matches.

It is clear that `&` is not a word character. That is why that substring with `&` symbols is not matched/captured.

> The first group should only contain anything which matches &[lmnor] (It can contain multiple of those if they are close together.

That is a case when we should be using a non-capturing group with a quantifier inside a capturing group: `((?:&[lmnor])+)`. We match the sequences of characters and capture all that chunk of text into 1 group.

> The second group should contain anything other than those letters.

It is a perfect job for a [tempered greedy token](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-quantifiers.html#tempered_greed): `(?:(?!&[lmnor]).)*`.  It matches any text that is not starting `&[lmnor]` substring. We cannot use a negated character class because the symbols to skip are 2 (not single character).

So, you can use the following regex:

```
((?:&[lmnor])+)((?:(?!&[lmnor]).)*)
```

See [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=((%3F%3A%26%5Blmnor%5D)%2B)((%3F%3A(%3F!%26%5Blmnor%5D).)*)&i=%26l%26mmabc%26od%26l%26r%26mef%26lg%26l%26e%26j%26rh)

There is another regex you can use that follows the same logics, but using a lazy dot matching and a boundary expressed with a positive look-ahead checking for end of string or with the first set of symbols `&[lmnor]`:

```
((?:&[lmnor])+)(.*?)(?=$|&[lmnor])
```

See [another regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=((%3F%3A%26%5Blmnor%5D)%2B)(.*%3F)(%3F%3D%24%7C%26%5Blmnor%5D)&i=%26l%26mmabc%26od%26l%26r%26mef%26lg%26l%26e%26j%26rh)

Comment: Lazy dot matching (version #2) yields 116,721 iterations per second, and the speed of the tempered greedy token solution is 137,537 ips, some 17% higher (tested at [regexhero.net](http://regexhero.net/tester)).

Answer (score 0):

It can be done with less complication using the built in power of
C# regular expressions.

This shows using the Capture Collections, and I believe is much faster.

C#

```
Match aM = Regex.Match(
             @"&l&mmabc&od&l&r&mef&lg&l&e&j&rh",
             @"^(?:((?:&[lmnor])+)(.*?))+$" );
if ( aM.Success ) {
   CaptureCollection cc1 = aM.Groups[1].Captures;
   CaptureCollection cc2 = aM.Groups[2].Captures;
   for (int i = 0; i < cc1.Count; i++)
      Console.WriteLine("[{0}] = {1}  {2}", i, cc1[i].Value, cc2[i].Value);
}
```

Output:

```
[0] = &l&m  mabc
[1] = &o  d
[2] = &l&r&m  ef
[3] = &l  g
[4] = &l  &e&j
[5] = &r  h
```